# Unable to delete a sharepoint online list Error "1 item was not deleted . Failed"

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, delete, delete-list

I have an empty SharePoint online list (which use to contain data), and when i try to delete this custom list using the UI, i got this error:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this error please?

Comment: Do you have full control permission on this list? Are you sure there are no items and list is empty? Also try deleting the items for this list from recycle bin and then try deleting this list.

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am the office 365 admin + the items were removed from the 2 stages recycle bins + i am the site collection admin.. not sure what is going on !

Comment: This is strange. Never faced similar issue before. Have you tried it deleting using PowerShell? Try [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the list through PowerShell.

```
$SiteURL = "site collection URL"
$ListName ="list name"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

If(Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName)
{
  Remove-PnPList -Identity $ListName -Force
  Write-host -f Green "List '$ListName' Deleted Successfully!"
}
Else
{
  Write-host -f Yellow "Could not find List '$ListName'"
}
```